# Quartz Lock Table Query is taking lot of time

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, quartz

I am new to Quartz Scheduler Framework. We are using it for scheduling purpose which has traffic around 200k requests to be scheduled. The trigger function was little heavy on computation side as it involves 2-3 API calls [sequential].

quartz config:

```
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          jobStore:
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
            isClustered: true
            clusterCheckinInterval: 20000
          threadPool:
            threadCount: ${QUARTZ_THREAD_POOL_COUNT:16}
```

**Problems**

1. We have deployed the service on Kubernetes with 6 pods and quartz threadPool count of 16. Unfortunately, we are seeing huge delay in task executing (around 2 hr).
2. We also observed that quartz locking was taking time (3-4 sec's).

```
SELECT * 
FROM QRTZ_LOCKS 
WHERE SCHED_NAME = ? AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE
```

What are the things I can do to improve the quartz performance?

Comment: I would say - use memory job-store instead of jdbc.

Comment: Do you have indices on schedule name and lock name? How many lock records does your database have? Did you profile your jobs? How much time are they taking in actual job execution and how much time in total, i.e. what's the overhead quartz is adding?

Comment: in the qrtz_locks, we only have 1 row. So, no indexing required. Avg Job Executing is arounf 5-8sec. Not much overhead added due to quartz

Comment: It doesn't look like you've configured Quartz to be in clustered mode. Was this intended?

Comment: Hi Lee, lately I tried with isClustered true [ will update the question]. But, still I am facing this issue

Comment: Your configuration looks much like mine except I use the Oracle delegate. I deployed a 2 pod configuration in the past like this and all was well. I did have ```spring.quartz.startup-delay: 20``` but I don't think that is the cause of your issue. Did you run the SQL command above by hand and get the delay and did you get the delay even after shutting down the pods?

Comment: Havent run that SQL command manually rather observed it in datadog while job's are executing.